# Download acceleration with jigdo?

Tags: download-manager

Im using jigdo-lite to download a Debian DVD ISO. I already have the CD version of the image, so I added the CD files to the task. Now I need to download many files (not all) of the DVD ISO.

The default jigdo-lite uses wget to download files. It seems jigdo (wget) downloads only one file at a time with one connection. So I'm getting a low download speed.

How can I accelerate the download speed using jigdo?

Possible Solutions:

1. Using different download manager with jigdo. Is it possible? If yes, How?
2. Using jigdo (wget) to download multiple files at once. How?
3. Getting download links of remaining files to download so that they can be downloaded with a download manager and later added to jigdo iso. How?

Comment: Since you're talking about Jigdo, I'll assume you're trying to download Debian or Fedora. Personally I haven't ever had a smooth download with Jigdo. What I do instead is use axel (`apt-get install axel`) and then use it, to download the image file.

Comment: For downloading iso there are many choices. But jidgo is way much better and downloads only the files that we need. The only downside is acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Seems i found the solution of getting the download links of remaining files. I would like to share it .

Firstly terminal or konsole might display only the last 1000 lines . We might have to change its settings to display unlimited lines.

Then disconnect internet and run the jigdo-lite as usual. It says numerous error messages saying failed to resolve website followed by download link of file. After it completes showing all messages, save the terminal output as a text file. This text file can be used with a download manager that can handle batch downloads .

The text file we saved will contain duplicate download links including mirrors. I got 3 duplicates for each file to be downloaded. So we must use a download manager that will skip already downloaded file. That's it.